# Performant SQL Join to retrieve most recent event

Tags: sql, join, teradata-sql-assistant

I have two tables in Teradata
T1: Sales data at the item/location/date level
T2: Price change data at the item/location/date level.

I need a performant (because at this level it's probably several million records) way to join these to pull the all the records from T1 (limited by date)  and the most recent price change at that item/location/date combination.

T1
| Itm | Loc | Date | Sales |
|-----|-----|------|-------|
| 1   | a   | 1/1  | 100   |
| 1   | a   | 1/2  | 200   |
| 1   | b   | 1/1  | 75    |
| 1   | b   | 1/3  | 50    |

T2
| Itm | Loc | Date  | Price |
|-----|-----|-------|-------|
| 1   | a   | 12/30   | 5.5     |
| 1   | a   | 1/2   | 5     |
| 1   | b   | 11/1  | 6  |
| 1   | b   | 1/2   | 7.5   |

Result
| Itm | Loc | Date | Sales | Price  |
|-----|-----|------|-------|---|
| 1   | a   | 1/1  | 100   | 5.5  |
| 1   | a   | 1/2  | 200   | 5  |
| 1   | b   | 1/1  | 75    |  6 |
| 1   | b   | 1/3  | 50    | 7.5  |

I've tried created a corss joined driver table (itm/date/location cartesian) but it's too much. I've tried ROW_NUMBER() to get the most recent price change, but I'd have to do that at every record, but gets me closer I think. I also tried makign a CTE of the price changes but can't figure out how to join so that I'm getting the most recent event from the price change table. Something like ...

```html
WITH CTE AS ( 
  SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PRICE.ITM, PRICE.LOCATION ORDER BY PRICE.DATE DESC) AS RN,
  PRICE.NEWPRICE
  FROM T2
  )
  SELECT 
  ITEM,
  LOCATION,
  DATE,
  SALES,
  (SELECT NEWPRICE FROM CTE WHERE T1.ITEM = T2.ITEM AND T1.LOCATION =T2.LOCATION AND T1.DATE>=T2.DATE)
  FROM T1
```

Answer (score 0):

So figured it out. I stuck with the CTE and lagged the previous date over a partition. Then joined where the sales date was between those price changes inclusive of the start. I'm sure it's not the most performant way to go about it but it works. Any enhancements would still be appreciated.

```html
WITH CTE AS ( DATE,
              ITEM,
              LOCATION, 
              NEW PRICE,
              LAG DATE OVER ( PARTITIONS ITM, LOCATION, ORDER BY DATE DESC) AS PREVIOUS_PRICE_DATE
              FROM PRICETABLE) P
 SELECT LOCATION, 
         DATE,
         ITEM,
         SALES,
         PRICE
 FROM SALESTABLE S
 LEFT JOIN CTE
  ON S.LOCATION = P.LOCATION
  AND S.ITEM =P.ITEM
  AND S.DATE >= P.DATE
  AND S.DATE < P.PREVIOUS_PRICE_DATE
```